# What's the best way to move packages from devdependencies to dependencies in bower.json?

Tags: angularjs, bower, bower-install

I've been working on an angular project and whenever I wanted a new package, I edited bower.json manually and added the package to `devdependencies` and then ran `bower install` to get the dependency installed.

I never really looked at the name of the section I was adding it to, but recently I ran `bower install <somepackage> -S` and it created a new section called `dependencies`. Ohhh!!! They're supposed to go there.

I looked it up and apparently `devdependencies` is for development dependencies, and can be excluded during a production build and is primarily intended for packages that support testing etc. However `dependencies` is included in both dev and production builds, and is intended for packages that will be in the final production build.

So now I have a lot of "production" packages under `devdependencies`. What is the best way to move them to `dependencies` without breaking anything?

Comment: cut and paste them from one section to the other?

Comment: @JBNizet Are there any problems with that? I'm using angular boilerplate. The instructions specifically say the install with `bower install --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Dependancies in bower will install to your `bower_components` folder regardless of whether you mark them as dev dependancies or not. Bower will always fill the `bower_components` folder with what is listed in `dependancies` and, depending on your instructions, possibly what is listed in `devDependancies`. In your case if you know which packages are only required for development you can just simply move them into the proper object. If things are working for you now with your dependancies in `devDependancies` then nothing will break if you move them to `dependancies`.

For example

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.11",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.11",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.11",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```

would become

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies" {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.11",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.11",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.11"
  }
}
```

As a side note, you should consider migrating your project to [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) per the recommendation by Bower themselves. You can find information on how to do that [here](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/).